# How can I determine fuse specs for the air handler's circuit board?

Tags: air-conditioning

where in the furnace does it say if it uses a 3 amp or 5 amp fuse for the circuit board? Or how would I know which is correct

Comment: Do you have a manual and/or wiring diagram, or even a make and model number?

Comment: the rating should be printed on the fuse itself

Comment: If it's a blade fuse like the ones below, there's a [color code](https://www.lifewire.com/car-fuses-and-links-explained-4018163) for each fuse rating just in case the rating is not visible.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been abandoned.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually indicated on the board itself as a consequence of the manufacturing process

**look closely just behind the fuse 3A**
[[image]][[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zWYA.jpg)www.amazon.ca

It should be documented in the service manual but this is a easier way to confirm. If you can't determine the size, always go with a 3A fuse. The difference between 3A and 5A on a circuit board is very significant. And a short on 3A board using a 5A fuse is very likely to blow a component.

**second method**

The board ID number is often specified and Googling the numbers on the board often takes you a valuable information source. This image shows a alternate location for the fuse size. [image]www.amazon.ca

Comment: Agree to play it safe. But the catch is that if it really should be 5A and the normal draw is, for example, 4A, then if a 3A replacement blows quickly you won't know whether it is the wrong size fuse or some other damaged component (or short circuit) causing a problem.

Comment: True but if the fuse continues to blows, you are officially in the trouble shooting mode. In all honesty the current draw of the board are minimal. I think the fuses are there more to stop dead shorts from techs and homeowners working on the stats.

Answer (score 0):

If the thermostat is relatively close a 3 should work.  Further away use the 5.  If the 3 blows try the 5. If the 5 blows, you have a problem in the furnace.